# bluez v5.50 - Cannot connect to Bluetooth earphones on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez

I have been running Ubuntu 19.10 for months on my notebook without a problem connecting my Bose Soundsport earphones. However, starting from a few days ago I could not connect the earphones using the default GNOME settings. I turned to using `bluetoothctl` from `bluez` v5.50 instead:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31
Attempting to pair with 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31 Connected: no
```

The device seems to be paired but was unable to connect. If I specifically attempt to connect the device, the following happens:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31
Attempting to connect to 4C:87:5D:B7:90:31
[CHG] Device A8:6B:AD:1B:97:2A RSSI: -84
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I already have `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` installed. `systemctl` gave the following errors:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-08 13:18:34 HKT; 1min 15s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 18813 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─18813 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Starting SDP server
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.204 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Mar 08 13:18:34 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.204 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Mar 08 13:19:33 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Device or resource busy
Mar 08 13:19:33 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
Mar 08 13:19:35 hwpang-ideapad-s540 bluetoothd[18813]: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
```

Any ideas?